# Terminate celery task within task

Tags: python, django, celery

Need your help. How can I run the celery task from the code with given time interval (every 3 min), max retries (after 5 attempts task should be terminated), in the given time period (task can work only from 9 a.m to 6 p.m.) and task has to terminate yourself when some condition occured within task (ordinal if-else statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, celery is just a tool to invoke tasks asynchronously. So in your case you only use celery to invoke task with interval and check attempts, periods and termination conditions inside the task, like:

**celery.py**

```
app = Celery('test_celery_app')
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'run-every-3-mins': {
        'task': 'celery.my_task',
        'schedule': 180.0
    },
}

@app.my_task
def my_task():
    if datetime.time(9, 0, 0) <= datetime.datetime.now().time() <= datetime.time(18, 0, 0):
        for try_count in xrange(5):
            # some operations
            if check_termination_conditions(): # condition to terminate task
                return
```